# cannot fill the screen even when I set fill_parent in ijkplayer

Tags: android, live, ijkplayer

we have a Live show module to do recently.

I have a question about the setAspectRatio(IRenderView.AR_ASPECT_FILL_PARENT) ,it is useless in my project.

we use the PLDroidMediaStreaming sdk to publish the live and get the playURL, At first, we want to integrate the PLDroidPlayer to play the rtmp, but our project had already integrated the ijkplayer before, there is always have a unsolvable FC conflict, so we use the ijkplayer at last.

But there is alway have a bug when playing the rtmp, there always have 10dp gap in both two sides, no matter set the type is fill_parent or fit_parent.

To test the rtmp is normally, we play the rtmp url in PLDroidPlayer , the frame is normally fill the screen.

so could you help me about the issues? thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

I fix it this morning, after initiall the videoview.
and setScaleX(1.1F)
and it will be ok